# How can I take the minimum of a sequence of multivariates?

Tags: r, plot, minimize

I want to get a sequence from 1-10

then I want to plot the minimum of log(i) and sqrt(i) for each i in 1:10.

```
x=seq(1,10,length=10)
y=min(sqrt(x),log(x))
plot(x,y)
```

But this returns a single value for y. I want it to take the sqrt of x and log of x then take the minimum for each x value.

Comment: Also worth noting that log(x) will always be smaller than sqrt(x).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `pmin` which gives parallel minimum across values and then you can `plot` the values.

```
x=seq(10)
y=pmin(sqrt(x),log(x))
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowMins` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
x <- 1:10
y <- rowMins(cbind(sqrt(x), log(x)))
plot(x, y)
```